# Matplotlib: Non-uniform fonts in .pdf after changing from Type 3 Font to Type 1 Font

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was asked to change some figures in my paper from using Type 3 Font to using Type 1 Font, and I found the [instruction](https://brainlogging.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/type-1-vs-3-fonts/)
to do just the job.

By adding the following 3 lines, I am able to generate a Type 1 Font .pdf file:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['ps.useafm'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.use14corefonts'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

However, while the font of x-tick and y-tick on my old plot were uniform, their fonts somehow became different after I added the 3 lines of code. This seems strange to me since the change is applied to only one of the ticks.

[image]

Here is the script in python:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('PDF')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages


# Switch to Type 1 Fonts. 
matplotlib.rcParams['ps.useafm'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.use14corefonts'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True


def plot_pdf_figure(path, title, xl, yl, xt_list, yl_list, style_list):
    fig = plt.figure(path) 

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel(xl, style='italic')
    ax.set_ylabel(yl)

    x_list = range(0, len(xt_list))
    plt.xticks(x_list, xt_list)
    for y_list, style in zip(yl_list, style_list):
        ax.plot(x_list, y_list, style)

    pp = PdfPages(path)
    pp.savefig(fig)
    pp.close()



plot_pdf_figure("test_plot.pdf", "test", "x-axis", "y-axis", [1,2,3,4,5,6], [[1,2,4,8,16,32],[32,16,8,4,2,1]], ["-ro","-gs"])
```

Thank you for any guidance or help!

Comment: It doesn't look like you are actually making the changes to rcParams. Try deleting the `'''` before and after that block?

Comment: It is meant for comparison. The current code will output Type 3 Font, but removing the ''' will output the Type 1 Font and the font difference can be observed. I will remove the triple apostrophes if it was unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of your `plt.xticks` call.

When `rcParams['text.usetex']` is `True`, MPL wraps ticklabels in `$`. For example, `ax.get_xticklabels()[0].get_text()` will give `u'0'` when `usetex` is `False`, and `u'$0$'` when `usetex` is `True`.

However, when you override the default tick-labels, you have to wrap them yourself, otherwise you get the sans-serif font. So, to fix this, I'd change your `plt.xticks` line to something like:

```
 plt.xticks(x_list, ['$' + str(xt) + '$' for xt in xt_list])
```

Here I'm using list comprehensions to loop over the ticklabels. I suppose it might also be possible to change the default sans-serif font family to be the same (serif) font as your serif family, but I think that may not entirely resolve the discrepancy between x- and y-labels since the strings are actually different.